# Is there any way to manually decrease the reference count of an object in Python?

Tags: python, c, reference, reference-counting

I'm using a C library that has a few memory issues. I've identified that sometimes it decreases the reference count too early, leading to segfaults, and managed to work around that by keeping a list of objects to inflate the reference count. On the other hand, I've also identified specific cases where the reference count is too high. Is there any way to work around these cases, from Python code, by purposefully decreasing the reference count?

I understand this is hackish and in no way clean code or anything, but I've got to deal with the buggy C library somehow, and it seems this might be easier than figuring out where the issue in the C code is (luckily it's open-source), fixing it, then recompiling it on all the platforms I have to support.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into the `weakref` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) module

Comment: @Brien: Hmm... not sure `weakref` would not help in this case. The C code itself is failing to do a `Py_DECREF` - a weakref would only allow me not to increase the reference count any more than it is. Although, I suppose I could go looking for a reference to the object I already own and turn it into a weakref... hmm...

Comment: You could try to use the Python C API `Py_DecRef` via ctypes. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/a798b16134d275b8cc8d947bead6f6543e019671 for an example that works around a memory leak in PySide.

Comment: @Claudiu My mistake.  When I read your question thought the C library was a separate example and you were trying to implement a similar functionality in pure Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Py_DecRef](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/refcounting.html) via ctypes:

```
import ctypes

_decref = ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef
_decref.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
_decref.restype = None

_decref(a_python_object)
```

Comment: just what i'm looking for - thanks! Also appreciated the PySide link to see how someone else did it.